# Add double quote to a string

Tags: php, string

How can I add double quote to this string.
The string I have

```
01-08-2022,02-08-2022,04-08-2022,05-08-2022,06-08-2022,14-08-2022
```

The string I want

```
"01-08-2022","02-08-2022","04-08-2022","05-08-2022","06-08-2022","14-08-2022"
```

Comment: explode original at comma, implode again with `","`, add missing `"` at the start and end ...

Answer (score 1):

Try with using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) method as below

```php
$oldString = '01-08-2022,02-08-2022,04-08-2022,05-08-2022,06-08-2022,14-08-2022';
$newString = sprintf('"%s"', implode('","', explode(',', $oldStr)));
echo $newString;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to CBroe's solution in the comment, you can also work with [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = '01-08-2022,02-08-2022,04-08-2022,05-08-2022,06-08-2022,14-08-2022';

$str = '"'.str_replace(',','","',$str).'"';

echo $str;
//"01-08-2022","02-08-2022","04-08-2022","05-08-2022","06-08-2022","14-08-2022"
```